# Materials become greyscale when building Windows executable from Linux machine

Tags: unity, materials, build-process

I have a whole build pipeline on a digitalocean Linux machine that does my builds for my game. I recently upgraded the entire project from some 2020 build to Unity 2021.3.8f1.

The problem is, now, the Linux machine (which uses the exact same editor script to build as my local build), has removed all textures or colors from the textures or something, because most of the 3d models are in pure white/greyscale. This was not a problem before now.

Linux build
[image: Linux build]

Windows build
[image: Windows build]

Interestingly, it's not all materials. Just the ones used for the character models and tiling. My first thought was that I change the color of these things programmatically based on game state, but I commented all that out and the problem persists.

Anyone have any ideas?

Please tell me I don't have to downgrade the project. God that would be annoying.

The command I use to build on the Linux side is as follows:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.15f1/Editor/Unity -projectPath "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/blah/blah/blah" -username ***** -password ***** -quit -batchmode -nographics -logFile "/var/lib/jenkins/blah/blah/buildwindows.log" -executeMethod JenkinsEditorScript.BuildGameClient
```

**Edit 1: I've confirmed this has nothing specifically to do with my game's code. I can reproduce this without writing a single script save the one that builds the game. Repro instructions**

1. Create a new project. Add a cube. Add a new standard material and change the color to green. Apply material to cube.
2. Add an editor script so that you can run the same build code for different machines. (No build options, standalone windows). Create a new folder called "Editor" in your assets folder and save the script there.

```html
using System;
using UnityEditor;

public class JenkinsEditorScript
{
    
    [MenuItem("BuildScripts/Windows Game Client")]
    public static void BuildGameClient()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("win build started");
        string[] levels = new string[] { "Assets/Scenes/SampleScene.unity" };

        BuildPlayerOptions bpo = new BuildPlayerOptions();
        bpo.scenes = levels;
        bpo.locationPathName = "Build/windows/SANDBOX.exe";
        bpo.target = BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows;
        bpo.options = BuildOptions.None;
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(bpo);
        Console.WriteLine("win build end"); ;
    }
}
```

3. Run the build through windows using the menu dropdown calling the script you just made.

[image: windows dropdown]

Upload your source somewhere to your Linux machine, then run the build through your Linux machine via command line. Pull the build folder off your Linux machines and compare it to the build from your windows machine.

```html
/var/lib/jenkins/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.15f1/Editor/Unity -projectPath "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/blah/blah/blah" -username ***** -password ***** -quit -batchmode -nographics -logFile "/var/lib/jenkins/blah/blah/buildwindows.log" -executeMethod JenkinsEditorScript.BuildGameClient
```

(note that these should be calling the exact same editor script you just made)

4. The cube is green in the .exe generated on the Windows machine. The cube is white in the .exe generated on the Linux machine.

Windows
[image: Windows build]

Linux
[image: Linux build]

Comment: *"Please tell me I don't have to downgrade the project. God that would be annoying."* When reverting the project to an earlier state is annoying to you, then I would recommend you to improve your version control strategy. For me, that would just be a simple `git revert`.

Comment: I use git as well. I just very cleverly haven't used/tested the build process in months.

Dumb me.